# Convert a variable to an integer

Tags: flutter, dart, integer, var

I tried to convert a variable (var) to an integer (int) because I need an integer to round the number.

I tried this code:

```
  var latitudee;
  int testoo;

    void testtest() {
        testoo = int.parse(longitudee);
        print('${testoo.toString()}');
      }
```

But I get this error:

```
Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
```

Comment: Without seeing the value of `longitudee` this is quite hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The radix exception usually means you are trying to parse non base-10 numbers.

Say for examples if you tried to parse an hexadecial number, like 'FF2', with
`int.parse("FF2");`, you get `Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)` exception.

Now if you specify the radix (16 for hex numbers), like `int.parse("FF2", radix: 16);`, you get the proper answer: `4082`

So basically, check that the `longitudee` is a proper number or set the proper radix.

Answer (score 0):

string to int

```
String s = "45";
int i = int.parse(s);


#int to string

int j = 45;
String t = "$j"
```